While getting the time from the RTC on the ESP32, there are gaps in milliseconds
I am using a timer interrupt on the ESP32 that triggers every 1ms. However, when I read the millisecond time from the RTC, there are gaps between the millisecond values.
How can I solve this issue? I am open to any ideas that might help simplify the solution.
Thank you very much.
Instead of the values increasing sequentially (e.g., 0.001, 0.002, 0.003, etc.), they are jumping (e.g., 0.001, 0.004, 0.007, etc.).
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <esp32-hal-timer.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <ESP32Time.h>

ESP32Time rtc(0);

volatile bool timer_flag = false;
hw_timer_t *My_timer = NULL; // Donanım zamanlayıcı oluşturuluyor
volatile unsigned long millisCounter = 0; // Milisaniye sayacı

void IRAM_ATTR onTimer() // Zamanlayıcı kesme fonksiyonu oluşturuluyor
{
  timer_flag = true;
  millisCounter++; // Milisaniye sayacını her milisaniyede bir arttır
}

void setup() 
{
 

  Serial.begin(115200);
  My_timer = timerBegin(1, 80, true); // Hesaplanan prescaler ile zamanlayıcıyı başlat
  timerAttachInterrupt(My_timer, &onTimer, true);
  timerAlarmWrite(My_timer, 1000, true); // Alarm her 10000 tikte bir (1 milisaniye @ 100 kHz)
  timerAlarmEnable(My_timer); // Zamanlayıcı alarmını etkinleştir

 
 
}

void loop() 
{
  if (timer_flag) 
  {
    timer_flag = false;

    // RTC'den zaman bilgilerini al
    int currentSecond = rtc.getSecond(); // Saniye bilgisini al
    unsigned long currentMillis = rtc.getMicros()/100; 

    // Sadece gerekli bilgileri yazdır
    Serial.print("Saniye: ");
    Serial.print(currentSecond);
    Serial.print(", Milis: ");
    Serial.println(currentMillis); // Sadece milisaniye kısmını yazdır
  }
}



I didn't try the code and don't know what this code is trying to accomplish. But microseconds/100 does not equal to millisecond. The library also provide a method for rtc.getMillis() in addition to the rtc.getMicros(), you could simply use that than doing the division yourself.

This is also posted in https://forum.arduino.cc/t/while-getting-the-time-from-the-rtc-on-the-esp32-there-are-gaps-in-milliseconds/1282899

@hcheung I have a project where I record data from an accelerometer to an SD card, capturing both accelerometer readings and timestamps (milliseconds). However, I'm noticing gaps in the timestamp data in my project's outputs. To determine if this issue originates from the RTC, I tried the code I shared above. For my project, I need to consistently capture consecutive millisecond data from the RTC. However, as I mentioned, I'm experiencing this issue. How can I solve this problem? Is there a way to consistently capture consecutive millisecond data from the RTC without these gaps in the data?

As I said, us/100 does not equal to 1ms, us/1000=1ms. I don't see how the code you shown us skips a ms. the currentSecond simply doesn't equal to the currentMillis. So if you have problem with your actual code, then show your actual code.
